# Delete duplicated rows in torch.tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates, pytorch, unique

I have a `torch.tensor` of shape `(n,m)` and I want to remove the duplicated rows (or at least find them). For example:

```
t1 = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
t2 = remove_duplicates(t1)
```

`t2` should be now equal to `tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])`, that is rows `1` and `3` are removed. Do you know a way to perform this operation?

I was thinking to do something with `torch.unique` but I cannot figure out what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply exploit the parameter dim of torch.unique.

```
t1 = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
torch.unique(t1, dim=0)
```

In this way you obtain the result you want:

```
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]])
```

[Here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique.html) you can read the meaning of that parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the use of the `dim` parameter for the unique function.