# Pytorch find unique vectors in tensor

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor containing binary values e.g

```
T1 = torch.tensor([[1., 0., 1.],
    [0., 1., 0.],
    [1., 0., 1.]])
```

i need to convert this to:

```
tensor([[1., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0.]])
```

I looked into `torch.unique` but it only works for values?

Is there a way to do the unique operation across entire vectors

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the result you're looking for, what is the ordering the rows based on? Could you give the desired result for an input `T2 = torch.tensor([[1., 0., 1.], [0., 1., 1.], [1., 0., 1.]])`?

Comment: the result: torch.tensor([[1., 0., 1.], [0., 1., 1.]])

Comment: Why would there be three elements in the second row since column n°3 has only 1s, is that a side effect of looking for unique values?

Comment: I'm looking for unique rows, not unique column values. So row 1 is the same as row 3, therefore I only return 1 of them

Answer (score 0):

Although the PyTorch documentation is not very clear the `dim` parameter can achieve this I found this post solving the issue [Delete duplicated rows in torch.tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66722985/delete-duplicated-rows-in-torch-tensor)

hence

```
torch.unique(T1,dim=0)
```

would solve the problem